# Laravel Group By Date

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to make an elqouent query for a following sql,

```
select sum(w.total_item_count) as Day_count, w.created_at as created_at from `sales_flat_orders` as `w` group by DATE(`w`.`created_at`) order by `w`.`created_at` asc
```

and I have tried this

```
$orderbydate = DB::table('sales_flat_orders as w')
                ->select(array(DB::Raw('sum(w.total_item_count) as Day_count'),DB::Raw('DATE(w.created_at) as created_at')))
                ->groupBy('w.created_at')
                ->orderBy('w.created_at')
                ->get();
```

I am getting correct output in sql query but not in eloquent query,
Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So guys, i have got the answer for this, Thank you for reading my question.

```
$orderbydate = DB::table('sales_flat_orders as w')
                ->select(array(DB::Raw('sum(w.total_item_count) as Day_count'),DB::Raw('DATE(w.created_at) day')))
                ->groupBy('day')
                ->orderBy('w.created_at')
                ->get();
```

The Raw query in my query was wrong for the created_at field. Now its good. Hope you will also get some input from this.

Answer (score -2):

```
$orderbydate = DB::table('sales_flat_orders as w')
                ->select(array(DB::Raw('sum(w.total_item_count) as 
                Day_count'),DB::Raw('DATE(w.created_at) as created_at')))
                ->orderBy('w.created_at')
                ->get();


$orderbydate->groupBy('w.created_at');
```