# How to get daily record and sum up

Tags: php, laravel, mariadb, laravel-query-builder

How to get the daily record and sum them up, plus group it by date? Please see my code below.

```
$sales = DB::table("orders")
    ->where('status', 8)
    ->select(
        'grand_total',
        'order_date',
        DB::raw("SUM(grand_total) as total_sales")
    )
    ->groupBy('order_date')
    ->get();

dd($sales);
```

It returns the right dates, but wrong sales. How can I sum sales each day?

Comment: Do you want to do this using query builder or via Eloquent collections?

Comment: Query builder. Since it is faster than eloquent.

Comment: Remove it from select `DB::raw("SUM(grand_total) as total_sales")` and add it like this `->addSelect(DB::raw("SUM(grand_total) as total_sales"))`
This should create a new query in existing one similar to this `"select SUM(grand_total) as total_sales from "orders""`

Comment: @maki10 Still the same.

Comment: Remove `grand_total`

Comment: @Jonjie Please dump sql query statement. Remove `->get()` add `->toSql()`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I did it by adding `DB::Raw('DATE(ord_date) day')` inside the select. I referenced this topic and I did a little bit work around.

Reference:

[Laravel Group By Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601782/laravel-group-by-date/26601951)

The problem is it also groupBy the time, which is wrong because I want to get the sales daily.